# GTK3 ComboBox shows parent items from a TreeStore

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, gtk3

I have a TreeStore that groups items into parent rows. Items from the Treestore can then be selected from a ComboBox.

[image: Imgur]

The user shouldn't be able to select the parent items, but GTK puts a selectable entry above its children in each cascading section.

I have tried using set_row_separator_func() to hide the parent rows, but it hides the expanding menu entry as well as the selectable cart.

The ComboBox is created with this code, and self.ObjectsList is shown on the left of the image:

```
self.gcombo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(self.objectsList)
renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
self.gcombo.pack_start(renderer_text, True)
self.gcombo.add_attribute(renderer_text, "text", 0)
self.gcombo.show()
```

Comment: Not sure what code I can add, it's just a standard TreeStore and ComboBox as far as I can see. I've pasted the combobox code anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sample program that does what you want:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

objectsList = Gtk.TreeStore(str, bool)

for i in range(2):
    parent = objectsList.append(None, ['Parent {}'.format(i), False])
    for j in range(2):
        objectsList.append(parent, ['Child {}'.format(j), True])

gcombo = Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(objectsList)
renderer_text = Gtk.CellRendererText()
gcombo.pack_start(renderer_text, True)
gcombo.add_attribute(renderer_text, "text", 0)
gcombo.add_attribute(renderer_text, 'sensitive', 1)
gcombo.show()

win = Gtk.Window()
win.add(gcombo)
win.show_all()
win.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)

Gtk.main()
```

You set the renderer's `sensitive` property to `False` in the parent rows and `True` in the child rows. That way, the parent rows won't be selectable.